# Unit testing with UI automation

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

... for .NET with VS Team System Test Ed?  Yes I know I should make my UI thinner, but I'm working with old code and I'd like to unit test the current state before I make major refactorings.

I've tried [NUnitForms](http://nunitforms.sourceforge.net/) and [White](http://www.codeplex.com/white), but they seem to have a non-obvious dependence on NUnit.  I get thread locking/managed code execution errors whenever I try to do use either to do an automatic UI operation.

What framework would you suggest I use?

Comment: Which UI platform? Windows Forms? WPF?

Comment: Seems to me like a dupe for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58213/can-you-recommend-low-cost-automated-testing-tools-for-a-net-winforms-applicatio

Comment: I didn't think White had a dependency on NUnit. It might use NUnit for it's own tests. White also did a good job of handling thread issues. I've used it in limited WPF testing and it worked. It worked even with modal dialogs.

Comment: You're right. After some searching I found a forum post http://white.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=64090 that explained how to get around the locking error I didn't understand. I just added InitializeOption.NoCache to my GetWindow() calls and the locking issue went away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the below SO questions:

[Can you recommend low cost automated testing tools for a .NET Winforms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58213/can-you-recommend-low-cost-automated-testing-tools-for-a-net-winforms-applicatio)

[Tools for automated GUI testing (on Windows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120359/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also check - Guia - Graphical User Interface Automation - http://guia.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Tutorial&referringTitle=Documentation

Bunch of useful articles focussed on .NET apps based automation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/site/cc301096